# Page cannot be displayed on page with auto-refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, refresh

I have an asp.net page with `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="300" />` and I find that IE10 sometimes gives "Page cannot be displayed" error.

My question is, can I write any code to force a refresh when that happens? Because a refresh always fixes the issue. Perhaps an addon for IE that provides an auto-refresh timer function?

Would it be any different if I create a timer on the page when it first loads and then do a Response.Redirect("Default.aspx") when the timer runs out?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.url.com" />
```

The above example would redirect but if you changed the 0 for another number it would wait that many seconds. Hope this all makes

Answer (score 0):

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.url.com" />
```

The above example would redirect  but if you changed the 0 for another number it would wait that many seconds. Hope this all makes